# Using Column headers to parse excel sheets using roo - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, import-from-excel, ruby-roo

Can we use column headers to specify the column number from which we are parsing the excel sheet using `roo` gem? My current code is like this now:

```
oo = Openoffice.new("simple_spreadsheet.ods")
oo.default_sheet = oo.sheets.first
(2..oo.last_row).each do |line|
  date       = oo.cell(line,'A')
  start_time = oo.cell(line,'B')
  end_time   = oo.cell(line,'C')
  pause      = oo.cell(line,'D')
  ...
end
```

I would like to parse from column headers instead of specifying columns as `'A' 'B' 'C' ..`. Can I acheive this using `Roo`?

Comment: as I know only digits or alphabet can be used to access a cell.

Comment: Why does the [roo website](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) hate my eyes so much?

Comment: @mu is too short..yeah..u r right..marvellous colors they got there :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the entire header row as an array and hash the entire row key'd on the header row.

```
oo = Openoffice.new("simple_spreadsheet.ods") 
oo.default_sheet = oo.sheets.first 
header = oo.row(1) 
2.upto(oo.last_row) do |line|  
  row_data =  Hash[header.zip oo.row(line)]
  ...
end
```

You could also use `row_data[line]` to nest the hashes for later use.

Comment: could you tell me how to write to xlsx and xls file using roo

Comment: You can't, at the moment roo only supports read for Excel. You can use axlsx gem to do writing. I know - it's not ideal, but so far I cant' find a gem that does both things well.

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner/clearer version of the above is

```rb
oo = Openoffice.new("simple_spreadsheet.ods") 
oo.default_sheet = file.sheets.first 
header = oo.first_row 
2.upto(oo.last_row) do |line|  
  row_data =  Hash[*header.zip(row).flatten]
  ...
end
```

the original took me a bit to understand because especially as i thought hash was a local variable named hash instead of the class Hash

Answer (score 2):

This will use the header row as the keys.  The helpful parts are transpose and strip.

```
def self.excel_to_hash(folder_name, file_name, tab_name)
    # Takes an excel file name and a tab name, and returns an array of stripped, transposed rows
    # Sample call:  my_data = excel_to_hash File.join(Rails.root,'db/data/data_to_import.xlsx'), 'models'
    rows = []
    file = File.open(File.join(folder_name, file_name), mode = 'r')
    excel = Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    excel.default_sheet = excel.sheets.index(tab_name) + 1
    header = excel.row(1)
    (2..excel.last_row).each do |i|
      next unless excel.row(i)[0]
      row = Hash[[header, excel.row(i)].transpose]      
      row.each_key{|x| row[x] = row[x].to_s.strip if row[x]}
      rows << row
    end
    return rows
  end
```

valid through Roo gem 1.10.2

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
 require 'roo'
    # open excel file
    excel_file = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file_path)
      # iterate on each sheet
      excel_file.each_with_pagename do |name, sheet|
        # iterate on each sheet
        sheet.parse(headers: true, pad_cells: true) do |row|
          # data should be access by column header if we have column header Name we can access like this
          row['Name']
        end
      end
    end
```